# JavaScript: Building table from AJAX response using DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, javascript-objects

I sending an AJAX request and I'm getting a JSON object as a response. I am trying to put the data in the JSON object into a table using the DOM API. Currently it is not working at all.

Can someone help me out with the logic of creating a table with DOM in this way? The wrong code I have tried writing is here:

```js
// AJAX request 

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fulldata;

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    fulldata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  }
}

xhttp.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/attainu-falcon/falcon-course-module/master/coding-challenges/data/books.json ", true);
xhttp.send();

// creating table using DOM

var table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute('class', 'tbl') document.querySelector('.div2').appendChild(table);

// from here nothing is working and I don't understand what to do. 

for (var i = 0; i < fulldata.length; i++) {
  var rows = document.createElement('tr');
  document.querySelector('.tbl').appendChild(rows);

  var cols = document.createElement('td');
  document.querySelector('.tbl tr').appendChild(cols);

  rows.innerHTML = < td > fulldata[i].author < /td>;
  rows.innerHTML = < td > fulldata[i].language < /td>;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that your code seems to expect the network request to be synchronous (ie, that `fulldata` is populated after the `xhttp.send()` function call has been issued).

In order for your code to work as required, you should instead build the table "inside" of the `onreadystatechange` function handler (ie at the point when `fulldata` is populated). One approach to this would be as follows:

```
// Define a helper function that creates and populates a
// table based on the provided json data
function buildTable(rows) {

  // Create the table    
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  table.classList.add('tbl');

  // Attach the table to document
  document.querySelector('.div2').appendChild(table);

  // Iterate each row of json data and insert row/cells
  // with author and language values of each row
  json.forEach(({ author, language }) => {

    let row = table.insertRow()

    row.insertCell().innerText = author
    row.insertCell().innerText = language
  })
}

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

// This function is called when a response is returned 
// from the AJAX request. This is the "asynchronous callback"
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    // If we reach this point, the request is understood to be
    // successful and we process the responseText as JSON and 
    // build the table
    buildTable(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
  }
}

// Execute the AJXA request
xhttp.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/attainu-falcon/falcon-course-module/master/coding-challenges/data/books.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/n3gxfmwj/) - hope that helps!